# Erro 400 ao chamar um serviço .net no app iOS - Como resolver?

Tags: .net, ios, web-service, xcode

Estou precisando acessar um webservice do meu app. Peguei um exemplo no stackoverflow para acessar o serviço http://www.cgsapi.com/CGSWebService.asmx. Abaixo o código-fonte para acessar o serviço. O problema é que estou recebendo erro 400 no response (header) e nenhum conteúdo no output. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que está errado?

```
-(BOOL)callWebService {
    NSString *soapMessage = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:cgs=""http://www.cgsapi.com/""><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><cgs:GetSystemStatus/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cgsapi.com/CGSWebService.asmx"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSError *error;

    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request addValue:@"www.cgsapi.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", soapMessage.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"http://www.cgsapi.com/GetSystemStatus" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"output: %@", output);
        if (error !=nil) {
            NSLog(@"error: %i %@", error.code, error.description);
        }
    }];

    [task resume];

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. O problema estava na composição da mensagem soap. Substitui as duas aspas duplas ("") por uma aspa simples (').

```
- (BOOL)validateCode:(NSString *)code {
    NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetSystemStatus xmlns='http://www.cgsapi.com/'/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cgsapi.com/CGSWebService.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSError *error;

    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request addValue:@"www.cgsapi.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", soapMessage.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"http://www.cgsapi.com/GetSystemStatus" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    NSLog(@"request: %@", request);

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"output: %@", output);
        if (error !=nil) {
            NSLog(@"error: %i %@", error.code, error.description);
        }
    }];

    [task resume];

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no .h

```
 NSMutableData *myData;
```

no .m

```
NSString *jsonPost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cgsapi.com/CGSWebService.asmx"];

NSData *postData = [jsonPost dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
request.timeoutInterval = 7.0;

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if(conn){ 
        NSLog(@"iniciando envio");
        }



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {    
    [myData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {  
    NSLog(@"terminei! estou alocado em myData");
  }
```

Comment: Olá @WilliamMonteiro

Não funcionou. Converti o conteúdo do receive e a mensagem de erro é: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Root element is missing.

Comment: Provavelmente isso é erro do parser, que vc esta usando.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o problema está no Content-Type que está usando, acho que o servidor está configurado diferente.

Tente isso, com o seu mesmo código:
`[request addValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: Realmente o erro 400 não esta ocorrendo mais. Porém tive que substituir na mensagem SOAP as "" por '. Agora o status code é 415 e a mensagem "The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported."

    NSString *soapMessage = @"<soap:Envelope xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetSystemStatus xmlns='http://www.cgsapi.com/'/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

Comment: Consegui!

O problema esta realmente nas duas aspas duplas que estava usando para compor a mensagem soap. Voltei o Content-Type para text/xml

O resultado é status code: 200

Abaixo vou postar a resolução.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu :) boa sorte com o restante.

Comment: Obrigado de qualquer forma Agora vou trabalhar no parse do retorno